# What on earth is the "Head On Live Television"

Tags: definition

[**This article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/man-threatened-shoot-nancy-pelosi-200733426.html) has a headline,

> A Man Who Threatened To Shoot Nancy Pelosi In **The Head On Live TV** Has Pleaded Guilty

Googling or [**googling on Yahoo image**](https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=Awr9Jhf8jj1hYpUA9FpXNyoA;_ylu=Y29sbwNncTEEcG9zAzEEdnRpZAMEc2VjA3BpdnM-?p=The%20Head%20On%20Live%20TV&fr2=piv-web&fr=yfp-t) shows no concrete hint what exactly it is.

I guess it is some kind of gadget with which you can watch T.V if you put it on one's ears?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading it like this:

> A Man Who Threatened To **Shoot Nancy Pelosi In The Head** On Live TV Has Pleaded Guilty

Comment: Ughh....thanks.